# Integral of a case function

Tags: definite-integrals

Assume the following function, with $x, a, b \in \! \mathbb{R}$

$$ 
f(x,a,b) =
\begin{cases}
  x+a+b & \mbox{for } ~ a-b \le x \le a+b \\
  0     & \mbox{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

How can the following integral be computed?

$$
I(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! f(x,a,b) \, \mathrm{d}a ~\mathrm{d}b
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain of integration can be changed since $f(x,a,b) = 0$ unless $(a,b) \in (-\infty,x]\times[x,\infty)$.  The result is:
$$I(x) = \int_x^\infty \int_{-\infty}^x (x+a+b) da \, db$$

However, this integral does not converge.

Update (original question was edited): The function is non-zero only if $a \in [x-b,x+b]$, so we can write:
$$I(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{x-b}^{x+b} (x+a+b) da \, db$$

This integral still does not converge.

Comment: And, more generally: an integral of a function defined in cases can be done by converting it to several integrals, one for each case.  Here, all other cases are zero, so Harry left them out.  A typical example of this is an integral involving absolute values.

Comment: For example, the first integral begins as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \, da$, but we can re-write this as $\int_{-\infty}^{x} f \, da + \int_{x}^{\infty} f \, da$ and the second integral is 0.

Comment: Will edit my original answer now to reflect the change in question.